# Date slicer doesn't support for dynamic query parameters in Between visual after binding to Parameter

Tags: powerbi

The Date slicer are configured as a Between visual at first.

After binding to parameter in Model:

[image]

A little warning `"The visual is producing a filter that's unsupported for dynamic query parameters."`

[image]

Note: it working find with `List` or `Dropdown` visual.

Any idea please?

Comment: Dynamic query parameters are still new and need some polishing. Probably between filter generates two separate where clauses, like `where column >= date1 and column <= date2`, which requires 2 parameters (while dropdown and list are using 1 parameter, with single value or list of values). Try to create 2 separate parameters, and bind them to two measures, calculating the min and max date from this column.

Answer (score 0):

The filter won't work with this type of date range filtering. Just change the type of the filter to either dropdown or list. Not sure this will cater for your problem.